# No IPV6 internet connectivity on client side of OpenVPN AWS EC2 server

Tags: amazon-ec2, routes, ipv6, openvpn

I have an OpenVPN server I've set up on an AWS EC2 instance that is pulling an IPV6 address, and can  `traceroute6` and `ping6` ipv6.google.com. The client can do neither and does not return an address when using online tests like ipleak, or testipv6. The server and client can `ping6` and `traceroute6` each other.

The client appears to pull the correct address locally, and via `ip -6 route`. IPV4 has always worked fine without issue. Everything appears good on the AWS side per their instructions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-migrate-ipv6.html#vpc-migrate-ipv6-cidr) so the instance does have ipv6 enabled with the proper routing on the aws/vpc side. Security groups are pretty wide open for ipv6 as well.

I am assuming it's my routing, but I'm not really sure at this point as I'm no ipv6 or routing expert. Please help!

Relevant config info:

ipv6 addr of AWS instance:
`aaaa:bbbb:cccc:dddd::/64`

server.conf

```
local 172.31.44.1
port 443
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh.pem
auth SHA512
tls-crypt tc.key
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "dhcp-option DNS 1.1.1.1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 1.0.0.1"
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-256-CBC
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
verb 3
crl-verify crl.pem
explicit-exit-notify
server-ipv6 aaaa:bbbb:cccc:dddd:80::/112
push "redirect-gateway-ipv6 def1 bypass-dhcp-ipv6"
push "route-ipv6 aaaa:bbbb:cccc:dddd::/64"
push "route-ipv6 2000::/3"
push "route 172.31.44.1 255.255.255.255 net_gateway"
push "dhcp-option DNS6 2001:4860:4860::8888"
push "dhcp-option DNS6 2001:4860:4860::8844"
```

/etc/sysctl.conf

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
net.ipv6.conf.all.proxy_ndp=1
```

ip6tables:

```
-A INPUT -p udp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m state --state NEW -i tun0 -o eth0 -s aaaa:bbbb:cccc:dddd::/64 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m state --state NEW -i eth0 -o tun0 -d aaaa:bbbb:cccc:dddd::/64 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use proxy NDP. It's a mess.
What you need is to delegate (=route) a prefix to the EC2 instance, then configure this prefix in the OpenVPN config (server-ipv6 keyword with the assigned prefix and mask, e.g. 2001:db8:dead:beef:1::/80), then assign connected users addresses from the prefix.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/work-with-prefixes.html
https://openvpn.net/community-resources/reference-manual-for-openvpn-2-4/